# Static Site generator, mvc, laravel or plain includes... what to use

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, model-view-controller, static-site-generation

I am having some difficulties of finding the right tools.
Of course the main sentence is: "it depends..."

I am still building small company sites while using "includes" for nav, footer, contactform and so on,
but what would be a better approach? No CMS, just static site, since updating will not be frequent enough.

I have been looking at static site generators like 11ty which would do the job, but also I am trying to get better at php, so should I look at laravel?

There is just so much on the market, that I am a little lost. What does the community use? It would be really great to get some ideas or examples.
Thank you so much in advance and have great day!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is a PHP framework, which you could use in creating your own CMS or static site generator if you really wish to challenge yourself and get better at PHP. In other words, pick it up if you wish to develop something backend oriented and interacts with a database.

I have used [Jigsaw](https://jigsaw.tighten.co/) once for static site generation, which is built with Laravel and uses Blade as a templating system and Markdown for its content formatting. Personally I think it's a good start to at least get acquainted with using Blade as a templating engine.

In my opinion, static site generation is frontend development where PHP isn't involved as much as you would like to think. If you wish to sharpen your PHP skills, try to create a CMS in something like Laravel or some other backend heavy application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have been looking for an alternative or a better way to work with includes, I will take a look at Jigsaw!